Stuck $200,000 of MATIC bridging from ethereum to polygon using SAFE
I created a SAFE on Ethereum and Polygon POS and bridged $200,000 of MATIC from the ethereum SAFE to the Polygon safe. The funds never arrived to the Polygon safe.
Steps Performed:

Created a SAFE on https://safe.global/ for polygon ([polygon safe][1])
Used Etherscan to create the same SAFE on Ethereum ([ethereum safe][2])
Deposited MATIC into the Ethereum SAFE
Started a bridge on [Polygon Portal][3] ([transaction][4])

Expected:
Matic deposited in polygon SAFE
Actual:
bridge still in "Pending" State over 1 week later
[![Pending State][5]][5]
Does anyone know a way to:

check the error messages for why this bridge is failing
fix the root cause

Potentially related polygon help article:
https://support.polygon.technology/support/solutions/articles/82000905001-why-can-t-i-bridge-my-funds-through-my-smart-contract-wallet-

this is not a developer question, please contact polygon support for help

If official bridge you can have to complete on ethereum and pay the final gas fee. Seemed to confuse a lot of people. Check if there is an option to complete the transfer on the same site you bridged from.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not developer related

I understand how stressful that must be. We can't do much on Safe's side as the transactions seem to have gone through. I can only advise to get in touch with Polygon's Plasma Bridge team here: https://support.polygon.technology/support/tickets/new
Hope they will be able to help. Best, Louis
